# MultiThreading in a forloop with parameters

Tags: java, multithreading

I believe am getting bad data because the instance variable are not thread safe.

I am trying to use multi-threading in a way that opens (at most) 13 threads *at a time* based on a list. I am using it in a service and need to pass parameters into the run method, so I made some instance variables and set them. I also want those thirteen methods to execute before moving on to the next iteration of the first for loop

```
private EnergyPortalGroup superGroup;
private EnergyPortalSubGroups singleSubGroup;
private BillingPeriod singlePeriod;
private DateTime[] dateTimeArray;

private void parseGroup(EnergyPortalGroup superGroup) throws InterruptedException{
    EnergyPortalSubGroupsCriteria criteria = new EnergyPortalSubGroupsCriteria();
    criteria.setGroupId(superGroup.getId());
    List<EnergyPortalSubGroups> wholeSubGroupList = subgroupsFactory.readList(criteria);
    for (EnergyPortalSubGroups singleSubGroup : wholeSubGroupList){
        this.singleSubGroup = singleSubGroup;
        this.deleteSubGroupRecordsFromDB(singleSubGroup);
        List<BillingPeriod> billingPeriodList = this.getPreviousTwelveBillingPeriods(singleSubGroup, superGroup);   
        if (billingPeriodList != null && billingPeriodList.size() > 0){
            Thread[] threads = new Thread[billingPeriodList.size()];
            for (int i = 0; i < billingPeriodList.size(); i++){
                this.singlePeriod = billingPeriodList.get(i);
                threads[i] = new Thread(this);
                threads[i].start();
            }               
            for (Thread thread : threads){
                thread.join();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my overridden run method:

```
@Override
public void run(){
    List<GroupSummarization> groupSummarizationsToWriteList = new ArrayList<>();    
    WidgetDataSummationHolder holder = new WidgetDataSummationHolder();
    holder = energyPortalService.getEnergyPortalWidgetsSummedData(singleSubGroup, null, null, singlePeriod);    
    parseSummationHolder(groupSummarizationsToWriteList, holder, singleSubGroup, dateTimeArray, singlePeriod);
    processBatchLists(groupSummarizationsToWriteList, superGroup, singlePeriod);
}
```

Can anyone help me make this thread safe? I am obviously new to multithreading and I tried passing these variables in with a constructor but I have some autowired services that were null and I was getting a null pointer at this line `holder = energyPortalService.getEnergyPortalWidgetsSummedData(singleSubGroup, null, null, singlePeriod);`

Comment: *"(at most) 13 threads"*? I don't see limit of 13 anywhere. Use a [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Comment: @Andreas ```Thread[] threads = new Thread[billingPeriodList.size()];``` Sorry, billingPeriodList will only be- at the most- 13 objects, so the array can only be a size of 13 or less. That, with join, creates 13 AT A TIME. Poor wording on my part, sorry

Comment: Create a custom class that implements runnable with a constructor that takes the data it needs so it becomes local to the runnable.

Comment: I tried that but I have another service that is autowired. It is null when I invoke a new instance of the class and I get a Null Pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I went with ExecutorService and a new class/service like a few suggested. So here is an example in case anyone else runs into this type of problem:

```
for (final Object x : list){
    List<Object> someList = getList();
    if (!Collections.isEmpty(someList)){
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<?>>();
        for (final Object n : someList){
            futures.add(executorService.submit(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    someOtherService.process(parameters)
                }
            }));
        }

        for (Future<?> f : futures){
             try {
                 f.get();
             } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                 //do some logging
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically this is calling an ExecutorService that manages the thread pool. I call newCachedThreadPool so that it creates new threads as needed instead of just assuming I know how many threads I would need in this case if you do see `newFixedThreadPool(n)`. But, to ensure I get some consistency on thread size, after I loop through the inner loop, I loop through the futures list (a future is `a future result of an asynchronous computation`) and call f.get which `waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result`...

This worked great for what I needed. And the key part is that inside of the overridden run function, the process method takes whatever parameters you want (notice the use of `final`) instead of trying to force feed run() or worrying about an autowired service when you are calling a constructor. This bypasses all of that.

Thank you to all who put me on the correct path

Answer (score 1):

energyPortalService cannot be null sometimes and not other times, given the code you provided. If it is not null when you launch a new Thread(this), then it should be there if you would use a new Thread(()-> {...});

(since you are talking about autowiring, I will presume a whole lot of foul play can occur with osgi and aop and such evils.)

Comment: Had to read up on this but autowiring happens after construction of a new instance (makes sense when you think about it). When that new instance is created it does not have access to energyPortalService through the constructor and is null. When I switched to using ```this``` instead of ```new Object(this.foo)``` it avoided the null pointer because I was using the same object. BUT, I was using unsafe thread practices by having the instance variables change while the threads were executing.

Very confusing at first, until I really sat back and thought about it. Hope this helps someone...